# Text Alignment problem

Tags: internet-explorer-6, alignment

How to control a running text? This is a user generated content, where user used to give with out giving space to the text. for example:

abcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefgh

This goes beyond the specific block. Is there is a way to wrap the text? how can i control it and i also want that to be worked in ie6 also...

Comment: Since you are "Webdevelopertut" and mention "ie6" I took the liberty of adding a couple tags to help people parse this question. Please change them if they're incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can make strings with no spaces wrap by using the following CSS property:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

According to the [MDC page on the word-wrap property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap), it is supported in IE 5.5+, Firefox 3.5+, and Safari 1.0+ (but not Opera).

Comment: That's because Mozilla adopted it late—you need Firefox 3.5+ in order for it to work. IE and Safari, however, seem to have had it for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `overflow:scroll;` in your CSS, this would put a horizontal scroll bar.  Should work in IE.